# Pubsub throttling, even with large queue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Our application suddenly experiences severe throttling when pulling messages off pubsub, using the REST API.

```
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${project}/subscriptions/${subscription}:pull
```

with json payload

```
{
  "returnImmediately":"false",
  "maxMessages":"100"
}
```

I've tried pulling different sizes, setting `returnImmediately` to `true`, but it still ends up only pulling 0 or 1 messages off our topic, even though there are 2-300k messages queued up.

Why is this? Can I tune the throttle any other way?

**NB:** The same code have been running without issues for months, pulling approximately 100 messages every request. Now we need to make 50-100 requests to get our batch of 100 messages -- essentially spamming the API.